# Inserting a Dictionary into a preexisting excel file, by date

Tags: c#, excel

The Data is stored in a Dictionary and arranged by month. (the string is what needs to be inserted.)

I have a preexisting excel file: it has all the dates of the year on the first column, and various entries in the following column. This data needs to be preserved.

My task is to basically insert the Dictionary into this excel file. What complicates things is that the Date value in the dictionary, needs to correspond to the date value in the excel column (date and month). To explicate: ("xxxx", 1980-05-12) needs to be inserted into the excel column with the first cell as "12-May" (this was generated via Fill->series).

And I have no idea. I'm spluttering by on bits of programming I'd picked up a couple of years ago. I've already extracted the data from the web page, and sorted it and all - automating some of the boring manual work. But I am faltering at the last mile, and seriously do not want to manually enter a couple of thousand data points when I know a simple script would suffice.

So, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void FindAndSetDate(WorkSheet ws, Dictionary<DateTime,string> dict)
{
    Range find = null;
    foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime,String> kvp in Dict)
    {
        find = ws.Cells.Find(kvp.Key, Type.Missing,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        if(find!=null) find.Offset[0,1].Value=kvp.Value;    
    }   

}
```

take a look at this thread [How to iterate through a column in an Excel application through C# Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488403/how-to-iterate-through-a-column-in-an-excel-application-through-c-console)

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." For Find.

Comment: Yeah. My excel app code is: 

`Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(path + @"\x");
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];`

Comment: take a look at link in bottom of my answer you will find the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel installed you could use [excel interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to fill the excel sheet. Formatting the date is easy with the [`DateTime` string format options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). In your case `myDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM")` would result in the desired format.